# Android gradle change resources on merge

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a json config file and I put it in res/raw folder. previously I have a gradle script that updates the file contents when it was necessary.

```
def fetchMeta(buildVariant) {
    def flavor = buildVariant.productFlavors.get(0).name
    def buildType = buildVariant.buildType.name
    def middleMetaFolder = "${buildDir}/intermediates/meta/${flavor}"
    def pathToMiddleMeta = "${middleMetaFolder}/latest.json"
    def rawFolder = "${buildDir}/intermediates/res/merged/${buildVariant.dirName}/raw/"

    def f = new File(pathToMiddleMeta)
    boolean doDownload = (!f.exists()) || (f.lastModified() < (System.currentTimeMillis() - 86400000))
    // Force on production release
    if (doDownload || (flavor == "production" && buildType == "release")) {
        new File(middleMetaFolder).mkdirs()

        def serverAddress = "https://example.com"
        String srcUrl = serverAddress + "/latest.json"
        println "Downloading Meta from: " + srcUrl + " to " + pathToMiddleMeta
        new URL(srcUrl).withInputStream { i -> f.withOutputStream { it << i } }
    } else {
        println "Skipping Meta as it exists here: " + pathToMiddleMeta
    }

    copy {
        from pathToMiddleMeta
        into rawFolder
    }
}
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.mergeResources.doLast {
        fetchMeta(variant)
    }
}
```

But as of android gradle plugin 3.0 merge strategy changed and files are with flat extension. How can I update the contents of my file after these changes?

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, which comes with the update from aapt to aapt2

issue is already assigned at google issue-tracker
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65220623

as a workaround right now you can set android.enableAapt2=false in your gradle.properties